# Unexpected value when getting value from a map

Tags: string, dictionary, go, slice

So I have a struct like this:

```
type Magni struct {
    ...
    Handlers map[string]func(*Message)
    ...
}
```

And I have a function to create a new instance of the struct:

```
func New(nick, user, real string) *Magni {
    return &Magni{
        ...
        Handlers: make(map[string]func(*Message)),
        ...
    }
}
```

But I can't get something from the `Handlers` map with the key `"hey"` when `"hey"` is in a variable, it only works if I type it myself. Here is a method of the struct `Magni` and `m` is a pointer to the struct `Magni`:

```
handler := m.Handlers[cmd[3][1:]] // cmd[3][1:] contains string "hey"
handler2 := m.Handlers["hey"]
```

For some reason, the value of `handler` is `nil` and the value of `handler2` is `0x401310`, basically I am not expecting `handler` to be `nil`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trimming the string solves the problem.

```
strings.TrimSpace(cmd[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the value based on the value of a variable works:

```
m := map[string]string{"hey": "found"}
fmt.Println(m["hey"]) // found

cmd := []string{"1", "2", "3", "hey"}
fmt.Println(m[cmd[3]]) // found
```

It even works if the variable is of `string` type and you slice its value, e.g.:

```
cmd = []string{"1", "2", "3", "Hhey"}
fmt.Println(m[cmd[3][1:]]) // found
```

You issue is most likely `cmd[3]` is the `string` `"hey"` itself, but if you slice it like `cmd[3][1:]`, it will cut off the first character (or to be precise: the first byte from its UTF-8 encoding sequence, the memory representation of `string`s, but the characters of `"hey"` map to bytes one-to-one), so it will be `"ey"`, for which you will not find any associated value in the map of course:

```
cmd = []string{"1", "2", "3", "hey"}
fmt.Println(m[cmd[3][1:]]) // NOT FOUND (empty string - zero value)
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/iGHq3PNzL6).

If `cmd[3]` is `"hey"`, no need to slice it, just use it as a key.

**Edit:** You claim `cmd[3]` contains the `string` `":hey"`. If it would, it would also work:

```
cmd = []string{"1", "2", "3", ":hey"}
fmt.Println(m[cmd[3][1:]]) // found
```

So your `cmd[3]` is not what you think it is. It may contain `0` bytes or unprintable characters. Print its bytes to verify. For example bytes of the `string` `":hey"` are: `[58 104 101 121]`

```
fmt.Println([]byte(":hey")) // Prints [58 104 101 121]
```

Print your `cmd[3]` to verify:

```
fmt.Println([]byte(cmd[3]))
```

You could also compare it to the `strings` you think it is, but that will only tell you whether they are equal (and won't tell you where the difference is):

```
fmt.Println(cmd[3] == ":hey", cmd[3][1:] == "hey")
```

Comment: Actually `cmd[3]` is the string `:hey` so `cmd[3][1:]` is `hey`.

Comment: @StianOK Then your `cmd[3]` is not the `string` `":hey"`. See edit to verify it.